# Why is my game not running and certain elements are not loading in?

Tags: javascript

I just made a simple game on visual studio code, where a player has to chase the square. But im not sure why its not running on the live sever ? I am very new to JavaScript and programming in general so please teach me like im a 5 year old thank you.

link to code
https://code.sololearn.com/Wb0dJ50Kto9d

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.height = 300
canvas.width = 300
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let player_x = 20
let player_y = 20
let base_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250)
let base_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250)


function step() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300)
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(player_x, player_y, 10, 10)
  ctx.strokeRect(base_x, base_y, 50, 50)

  if (player_x >= base_x && player_y >= base_y && player _x <= base_x + 50 && player_y <= base_y + 50)
    console.log('YOU WON') {
      let base_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250)
      let base_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250)
    }

  requestAnimationFrame(step)
}
requestAnimationFrame(step)


function handleInput(event) {
  var key = event.key
  if (key === 'a') {
    player_x -= 5
  } else if (key === 'w') {
    player_y -= 5
  } else if (key === 'd') {
    player_x += 5
  } else if (key === 's') {
    player_y += 5
  }

  document.addEventListener('keypress')
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Epic Square Game MK 1</h1>
  <main>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </main>
  <section>Score: <span>0</span></section>

</body>

</html>
```

I followed a youtube video to do this as im new and just wanted to get stuck in.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3OnwkPOfY4

Comment: Other than certain things not loading - is there an error msg?

Comment: JavaScript Console
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Line: 1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Line: 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot happening in your code. I understand that when learning it's easy to overlook certain aspects. So what I would recommend is to learn how to **debug**. In basic terms it means that whenever an error occurs you learn what the error means and how to approach it.

In this case you got this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' Line: 1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Line: 19

It ways that on line 19 there is a `SyntaxError`. Which means that you probably have made typing error. The *token* `<` that should not be there or is not expected. So lets check out that line.

```
if (player_x >= base_x && player_y >= base_y && player _x <= base_x + 50 && player_y <= base_y + 50)
```

It seems that you added a space at `player _x` which makes the next character `<` unexpected. Remove the space.

When fixing that another error occurs:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' Line: 20

Also a syntax error, so again probably a typo. If you look closer you'll see that the *curly braces* of the `if` statement come after the `console.log('YOU WON')`. You probably intended to do this:

```
if (yourstatement) {
  console.log('YOU WON')
}
```

Notice the log message inside the curly braces.
Now you've fixed this one another error occurs. Welcome to the debugging hell of JavaScript. It's hard in the beginning but if you learn from the errors you'll save yourself a lot of headaches.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Line: 45

This error tries to say. "You started something but never closed it". So look for maybe a function or code block which opens but never closes on that line. In this case it is the `handleInput` function.

```
function handleInput(event) { < opens
  ...
} < closes
```

Add a curly brace at the end and it is fixed.
And then, the last error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
>   Line: 44

This one is telling you that the method `addEventListener` requires 2 arguments. Right now you've only giving it one. This method has to know **which** event to listen to and **what** it should do when it is fired. So add the `handleInput` function as the second argument and you are good to go.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', handleInput);
```

The snippet below contains all the fixes mentioned above. Check it out and compare it with your own code.

Research your errors and learn what they mean. They sound very cryptic at first, but you'll get the hang of it.

Hope this helps you out and my explanations are coherent enough to understand.

**NB** Try to add semicolons to the end of each line where you call a function, declare or assign a variable. It is not mandatory to do it, but could prevent your code from breaking unexpectedly. Look in the example below to see in which places I've added the semicolons.

**Edit** You were on the right path to make the game reset when you win. My previous edit freezed the game whenever you won. Now the reason it wasn't resetting at first was because of the `let` keywords inside the `if` statement inside the `step` function.

By using `let` inside the `if` statement you declare new variables that only exist inside the `if`. These variables are considered as new and don't relate to the existing variables with the same name. And because you use `let` it can be the same name as another variable that exists globally, or in another scope.

When you remove `let` you use the existing `base_x` and `base_y` variables you declared earlier and give them new values.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.height = 300;
canvas.width = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let player_x = 20;
let player_y = 20;
let base_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
let base_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);

function step() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(player_x, player_y, 10, 10);
  ctx.strokeRect(base_x, base_y, 50, 50);

  if (player_x >= base_x && player_y >= base_y && player_x <= base_x + 50 && player_y <= base_y + 50) {
    console.log('YOU WON');
    base_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
    base_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);

function handleInput(event) {
  var key = event.key
  if (key === 'a') {
    player_x -= 5;
  } else if (key === 'w') {
    player_y -= 5;
  } else if (key === 'd') {
    player_x += 5;
  } else if (key === 's') {
    player_y += 5;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', handleInput);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 5px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Epic Square Game MK 1</h1>
  <main>
    <canvas></canvas>
  </main>
  <section>Score: <span>0</span></section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much this is amazing description. I really apprectiate the time you put into this and my games working yippe

Comment: one problem the square is supposed to reset when the player touches it aka move to a new spot

Comment: You are correct. It didn't work before so thought it might have been part of the process. I've added the solution and explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the errors:

- line 31: there is a space between player and _x, remove it, it should be
  player_x
- line 32: the opening curly bracket should be before console.log
- line 53: you need to add a closing curly bracket to close the
  function handleInput(event)
- line 55: you need to pass handleInput to addEventListener:

  ```
   document.addEventListener('keypress',handleInput)
  ```